# Creating row clickable tables in sencha touch 2from the Store

Tags: sencha-touch

Hello every one i Am using sencha touch 2 .I wanna create a table where data comes from a store .and on clicking the row i can fetch the data of the  clicked row. Can anybody help me regarding this. 
I have used the Ext.ux.touch.grid but its not solving my problem .

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Xtemplate to render your store data into list or table or any other format you want. You should put unique id of each record in some dom attribute so that when tapped you can check which element was that and what should be done for that record.

Look at [touchstyle](http://www.shopstyleapp.com/app/) example in sdk, they are using similar strategy.